# How to filter posts by category in Camaleon CMS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, camaleon

I am trying to filter posts by category in my Rails project, I am using Camaleon CMS. My basic requirement is to display only specific posts.

For example, only those posts to be shown who belong to the category "Fruits"?

Here is the code I have used:

```
  <% current_site.the_posts(current_theme.get_field("recent_post_type")).latest.limit(current_theme.get_field("home_qty")).decorate.each do |post| %>
      <!-- PORTFOLIO ITEM -->
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 text-center discussion-bot-box">
        <h4><%= post.the_title %> <span>(299)</span></h4>
        <p><%= post.the_content.html_safe %></p>
      </div> <!-- /col -->
  <% end %>
```

Comment: You can use `current_theme.the_posts.where(category: 'fruits')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try finding the category first:

```
category = current_site.the_full_categories.find_by(name: 'Fruits')
```

then decorate and get the associated posts:

```
category.decorate.the_posts
```

Comment: this is awesome, i can't express how much glad i am, thank you so much for this, can you please tell me from where did you get this? i mean do you have any link where this information is available.

Comment: Camaleon CMS documentation is not the best and most of the stuff I just go look at the source code.